# MySQL syntax error with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, windows, wampserver

I'm having a problem with MySQL 5.5.24 and PHP 5.4.3. I have the following HTML/PHP Code:

```
<?php
function connect() {
    $con = mysql_connect( "127.0.0.1", "root", "" );
    if ( !$con ) {
        die( "Could not connect: " . mysql_error() );
    }
    mysql_select_db( "game" );    
}

function protect( $string ) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string( strip_tags( addslashes( $string ) ) );
}


if ( isset( $_POST[ 'register' ] ) ) {
    connect();
    $username = protect( $_POST[ 'username' ] );    
    $register = mysql_query( "SELECT 'id' FROM 'user' WHERE 'username'='$username'" ) or die( mysql_error() );
    if ( mysql_num_rows( $register ) > 0 ) {
        echo "That username is already in use!";
    } else {
        $ins = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO 'user' ('username') VALUES ('$username')" ) or die( mysql_error() );
        echo "You have registered!"; 
    } 
}
?>
<form action="register.php" method="POST">           
Username: <input type="text" name="username"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="register" value="Register"/>
</form>
```

Whatever I input, MySQL will always return

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''user' WHERE 'username'='XXX'' at line 1"
```

I checked these queries with phpmyadmin and they work just fine! There is also no connection problem. I even tried plain `"SELECT * FROM 'user'"` with the same result. I simply do not get any response, just the mentioned error about malformed SQL syntax.

Now I checked tons of articles having the same error and in each case the problem was having used a keyword of PHP or missing/mispelling a variable name and that kind. I checked my statements a hundred times now and I can't find any error. I'm quiet new to PHP so maybe I miss something...

One of my last experiments was changing the collation of the database as well as the storage engine, also with no result...

Hope you guys see what I can't! :-)

BTW, I'm running Windows 7 and WAMP 2.2.

Comment: Maybe you should rename `protect()` to `mangle()` ;)

Comment: Generic filtering functions are bad. `mysql_` is also bad. Give PDO and prepared statements a try!

Comment: for the table names, either use back ticks `, or don't use any quotes for table names at all: SELECT id FROM user...

Comment: Specifically, code like yours is the reason my last name always comes out as `O\\\'Hara`. Please don’t.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 'id' FROM 'user' WHERE 'username'
```

Change `'` to `` ` `` (back quote)

what you are talking about table names and column names you should use backquote. when you are talking about strings (like values) then use single/double quotes

Answer (score 1):

You should use backticks (not quotes) when writing names:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `username` = 'foo'
```

Quotes are for string literals.

By the way your `protect` function is a bad idea. I would recommend that you avoid using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Use parameterized queries in either mysqli or PDO.

**Related**

- [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)